# Can someone help me with solving this beam problem using Rayleigh Ritz Method, my trial function is not working

Tags: beam, finite-element-method

The question is there is a two element beam joined together. The first element is 5m long and the other is 4m long. At the outer nodes there are roller supports and at the middle point where two elements meet is the point support. Q = 5000 N is the distributed load all over the beam. I tried to solve this using Rayleigh Ritz method .

I choose the trial function Y<sub>approx</sub> = a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>X + a<sub>2</sub>X<sup>2</sup> + a<sub>3</sub>X<sup>3</sup> + a<sub>4</sub>X<sup>4</sup>

The boundry conditions are:

- y(0) = 0;
- y(5) = 0;
- y(9) = 0;
- y"(0) = 0;
- y"(9) = 0;

When I solve for the values of the constants I get a1 and a4 = 0

What should I do can someone please help?

Picture for reference:[image: the image has been described above]

Comment: Why would y'' be 0 at those points? As opposed to something like y'(2.5)=y'(7)=0?  To top that off, the middle support introduces a point (reaction) load so you may be better off splitting it in two at x=5, as point loads tend to produce non-contiguous slopes in geometries.

Comment: `Can someone help me?` is not an engineering question

Comment: @Abel y"=0 because there's no bending moment at 0 and 9. OP I think your shape function is a bad choice, obviously the bent shape resembles 1.5 cycles of a sin wave so is much higher than x^4. Also you should scale x by 9, just for neatness. That being said I have zero experience with using RR to get a deflected shape, I just use it for mode shapes.

Comment: Some sensible problem with the given info and tooling instead might be: supposing you load it and then remove the load, what geometry makes sense for a dynamic response?

Comment: I just thought of a sneaky approach. Solve it properly in the usual fashion. Then fit a polynomial to the deflected shape. Then you'll know how many terms you need.